# UIAlertView appears toooo short after loginButton action called

Tags: ios, authentication, request, action, uialertview

i want to show an UIAlertView while the LoginProcess is working OR after the loginButton action is called. Here is my code:

```
- (void) btnLogin:(id) sender {

    UIAlertView *alertLogin = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"\nLogin in progress, please wait!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertLogin show];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/login/"];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setPostValue:username forKey:@"username"];
    [request setPostValue:password forKey:@"pw"];

    [request startSynchronous];
    [request cancelAuthentication];

    [...]
}
```

1. i press the login button.
2. the screen gets an gray radial overlay

**3. the loginprogress is done AND NOW the UIAlertView appears very very shortly.**

I want to display the UIView **WHILE** the login is in progress and not after.
I cant find out why this appears after the progress.
Need help.
Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .h of your class

```
UIAlertView *alert;
```

In .m btnLogin Method

```
    alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login in progress\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
```

[alert show];

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

// Adjust the indicator so it is up a few pixels from the bottom of the alert
indicator.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height - 50);
[indicator startAnimating];
[alert addSubview:indicator];
[indicator release];
```

In didRecieveData Method of connection, you will write, or if you are parsing, then didEndDocument method of parser, you can do

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Hello Veer, that does not work. the screen is blocked while login progress/loading. you have recommended me MBProgressHUD but there is the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in `[request startSynchronous];`

sync http requests and UI don't go well together. Try using and async connection